# WPF ResourceDictionary StringFormat XamlParseException

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I have a ResourceDictionary with a Style defined that has a ControlTemplate with a Binding StringFormat as below:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalCash, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0:N2}, FallbackValue=0.00}" />
```

I run locally and everything is fine but I do a build and install on a server and I get the following exception when I launch any WFP screen which makes use of the ResourceDictionary:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Unexpected token after end of markup extension.' Line number '224' and line position '148'. ---> System.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Unexpected token after end of markup extension.' Line number '224' and line position '148'.
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.MePullParser.<Parse>d__0.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<LogicStream_Attribute>d__6f.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_EmptyElement>d__14.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_Element>d__7.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementContent>d__4a.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementBody>d__23.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_Element>d__7.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementContent>d__4a.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementBody>d__23.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_Element>d__7.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementContent>d__4a.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementBody>d__23.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_Element>d__7.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementContent>d__4a.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementBody>d__23.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_Element>d__7.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementContent>d__4a.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementBody>d__23.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_Element>d__7.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_PropertyContent>d__5f.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_NonemptyPropertyElement>d__42.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_PropertyElement>d__35.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementBody>d__23.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_Element>d__7.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementContent>d__4a.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementBody>d__23.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_Element>d__7.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementContent>d__4a.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_ElementBody>d__23.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<P_Element>d__7.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.XamlPullParser.<Parse>d__0.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.NodeStreamSorter.ReadAheadToEndOfAttributes()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.NodeStreamSorter.ReadAheadAndSortCtorProperties()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.NodeStreamSorter.MoveNext()
   at System.Xaml.XamlXmlReader.Read()
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo, IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector styleConnector)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
```

I did some digging and got it to work by changing the ResourceDictionary StringFormat from {}{0:N2} to N2:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalCash, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=N2, FallbackValue=0.00}" />
```

The following works which put in a UserControl:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalCash, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0:N2}, FallbackValue=0.00}" />
```

My question is why does the same StringFormat work in a UserControl but not a ResourceDictionary? I'm happy it's working but would like to understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [WPF bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2b877e2d-bfee-48be-8884-5d3811e58d52/).

I'm guessing that you have .NET 4.5 installed locally on your development machine (because Visual Studio 2012 is installed, perhaps), but not on your server (which only has .NET 4). Thus, your server doesn't have the bugfixes that Microsoft added to WPF in .NET 4.5.

Comment: Pretty scary. Yes, developing .Net 4.0 WPF app using VS 2012. I would have expected that setting the Target framework to .Net 4.0 would have resulted in consistent behavior. Guess we better not updated our test servers to 4.5. This could have been a disaster if rolled out to clients.

Comment: @KornMuffin: Unfortunately, targeting .NET 4 in your project properties doesn't really make much difference if .NET 4.5 is installed locally (because it's an in-place replacement that overwrites the .NET 4 DLLs). The compiler will prevent you from calling new .NET 4.5-only APIs, but you will never be able to know how your app actually runs under .NET 4 without testing it on a dedicated .NET 4 machine. See this [suggestion to Microsoft](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3127346-support-a-net-4-0-service-pack-on-windows-xp-supp) for more details.